# Neo4j, Capistrano deployment, Authentication error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, capistrano, neo4j.rb

I want to deploy a Rails application, using Neo4jrb, to production with Capistrano. During deployment the following error shows up:

```
DEBUG [5a528d81] Finished in 0.057 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [acd66fd5] Running /usr/local/bin/chruby-exec 2.3.0 -- bundle exec rake assets:precompile as deploy@46.101.153.252
DEBUG [acd66fd5] Command: cd /home/deploy/projects/larp-tool/releases/20160522103925 && ( export RAILS_ENV="production" ; /usr/local/bin/chruby-exec 2.3.0 -- bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
DEBUG [acd66fd5]    rake aborted!
DEBUG [acd66fd5]    Neo4j::Server::Resource::ServerException: Expected response code 200 Error for request http://localhost:7474/db/data/, 401
DEBUG [acd66fd5]    /home/deploy/projects/larp-tool/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/neo4j-core-6.1.4/lib/neo4j-server/resource.rb:37:in `handle_response_error!'
/home/deploy/projects/larp-tool/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/neo4j-core-6.1.4/lib/neo4j-server/resource.rb:32:in `expect_response_code!'
/home/deploy/projects/larp-tool/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/neo4j-core-6.1.4/lib/neo4j-server/cypher_session.rb:86:in `initialize_resource'
...
```

I set the following credentials in `neo4.yml`:

```
production:
  type: server_db
  url: http://username:password@localhost:7474
```

and also tried:

```
production:
  type: server_db
  url: http://localhost:7474
  username: username
  password: password
```

I set up this credentials with the Neo4j REST Api, and when I run `curl` on the server everything seems fine:

```
curl http://username:password@localhost:7474/db/data/
```

So, why is there an error during deployment?

Comment: which task is trying to connect to the db ?

Comment: it seems to be `rake assets:precompile`, but i don't unterstand why...

Comment: `assets:precompile` needs to load the Rails environment which will use the `railtie` from the `neo4j` gem, which opens a session to Neo4j upon initialization of the Rails app.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your `neo4j.yml` files looks fine on to me.  The `401` in the error means that the authentication isn't working.  There are a few possibilities:

- Have you set the password in Neo4j on production by logging into the web interface?  Neo4j doesn't allow you to connect with the default username / password via the HTTP endpoints (which the gem uses) and so you need to change it.  If you set up the database locally with the `rake` tasks you probably didn't hit this because they setup the server without authentication to ease this process along.
- You could try setting the `NEO4J_URL` environment variable to `http://username:password@localhost:7474` to see what you get
- As a sanity check: Is your Neo4j database running on the same server as your app (otherwise `localhost` wouldn't make sense)?